# Samsung Galaxy Nexus - Add new contacts from call log screen

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-nexus, call-history

Using the Samsung Galaxy Nexus, How do you add new contacts using a number from the call log screen? According to the manual there should be a +contacts button but I do not see it.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to risk the fact that Samsung probably makes this mechanism similar across systems. On my Samsung Galaxy S3, from the phone log entry, hard press the intended number until the context menu comes up after a second or so. Select 'Add to Contacts', and a contacts template comes up for the intended data, which allows you to add to an existing contact or create a new one.